# Oracle SQL : can't create procedure

Tags: sql, oracle

I am learning SQL and developing my application in Oracle Apex. I am trying to make this procedure but I get this error when I try to compile it:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "@" when expecting one of the following:   current delete exists prior

Basically I am trying to update `completed_orders` value in my `manager` table by `manager_id` identifier

```
create or replace procedure update_manager_comp_orders (@manager_id_value  NUMBER, @comp_orders NUMBER)
as
begin
    update manager
    set completed_orders = @comp_orders
    where manager_id  = @manger_id_value
end;
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-321084DE-3BDD-484B-AE85-7A991B67C51A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the sign `@` before the parameter name, also from the body of the procedure!!

```
 create or replace procedure update_manager_comp_orders (manager_id_value  NUMBER, comp_orders NUMBER)
as
begin
    update manager
    set completed_orders = comp_orders
    where manager_id  = manger_id_value;
end;
```

Comment: All the statements in PL/SQL should be terminated by semicolon.